# Applying new configuration settings to Nginx without downtime?

Tags: nginx

What is the best way to apply config changes to Nginx without users experiencing errors (requests being denied or exited)?

I have scoured the interwebs and no place can give a definitive answer to this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
nginx -s reload
```

You can:

```
kill -HUP $NGINXPID
```

Found by searching 'nginx reload config', first hit is the [CommandLine](http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine) page on the nginx wiki.

Comment: Yeah those are the two commands I've consistently seen. But which is better?

Comment: I don't think it matters much, they should both work.  It may be easier to use the `nginx -s reload` command since you won't have to track down the PID of nginx.

Answer (score 1):

```
nginx -s reload
```

and

```
kill -HUP $NGINXPID
```

do the very same thing, sending the main nginx process SIGHUP.